# Must a svg be inline to query one of its nodes with javascript?

Tags: html, animation, svg

I usually put the svg I want to animate using javascript inline, or I cant get one of its node, whether it is by id or class, or using jquery or vanilla JS.

Is there a way to query an SVG node if it is not inline?

With an object, I can't get it to work.

```
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="/assets/images/logo.svg"> 
    <img src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
  </object>
```

My javascript file is called at the end of the `body` node and I wrapped my code in a  `$(document).ready()` function.

---

EDIT: the svg dom nodes are indeed in the page code, but when I try a `console.log(document.getElementById("item_id"))` it doesn't return anything, both on Chrome and Firefox, with ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics should be part of your page's DOM, and visible to javascript, if your out-of-line `<svg>` object is loaded with an `<object>` tag.

But not if you load it with an `<image>` tag.

(Chrome).

Comment: What do you mean,"(Chrome)". Does that mean it is a chrome only technique? I already tried with object but it didn't work, see my updated question.

Comment: It means I've tested this on Chrome, not any other browsers.